# Conditionating the routing on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, routes, propel

Hello I need make some conditions for the all the routes that are on my routing. In a little explication I have a DB that contains users and profiles or roles like you wanna to tell that. on this DB I have too a collection of routes that each profile or role can use or access. I need that before the routing load the controller, I can review if the user have the necesary profile for access to this route.

Notes:

I am using Propel 1.2.* with Symfony2.4

The query that i am using for that is the next:

```
$permisos = MenuQuery::create()
            ->useAccesoMenuQuery()
            ->usePerfilQuery()
            ->usePerfilUsuarioQuery()
            ->filterByUsuarioId($usuario->getId())
            ->endUse()
            ->endUse()
            ->endUse()
            ->groupBy('menu.id')
            ->find();
```

The relation between the tables is that:

```
(FK = ID)User 1-----> ∞ User_profile ∞ <-----1 profile(FK = ID)
```

I wait that someone here can help me with that I need solve that...

Really Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2 has it's own logic for authentication as well as authorization. You shoud take a look at the [security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) part of the Symfony documentation. If all you need is just checking roles against routes it's all there.
The FOS [UserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) might interest you as it provides additional features recommended by the symfony documentation itself.